# Use JsonDocument with SQL Server in EF Core 7. The LINQ expression cannot be translated

Tags: c#, linq, invalidoperationexception, ef-core-7.0

I am using EF Core 7.
I have a requirement to save dynamic `json` at run time.
I am using the `System.Text.Json.JsonDocument` class in the class, as shown below.

```
public class SomeEntity : IDisposable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public JsonDocument JsonDocument { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        JsonDocument.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The application can use `SQL Server` or `PostgreSQL`.
When using `PostgreSQL`, the `JsonDocument` type is converted to `jsonb` in the database. I am able to save and query the `json` data without any problems.

```
await _dataContext.SomeEntities
                    .Where(x => x.JsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("Name").GetString().Contains(name)
                    )
                    .OrderBy(x => x.JsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("DOB"))
                    .ToListAsync();
```

However, when using `Sql Server`, I have to provide a `Converter OnModelCreating` in order for the `JsonDocument` to work.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>().Property(e => e.JsonDocument).HasConversion(new JsonDocumentConverter());
}

public class JsonDocumentConverter : ValueConverter<JsonDocument, string>
{
    public JsonDocumentConverter() : base(
        d => d.RootElement.ToString(),
        s => JsonDocument.Parse(s, default))
    { }
}
```

Using the converter, the `JsonDocument` will be translated to `NVarchar(MAX)` in the database.
Saving data is working fine, but I am not able to query the data in the JsonDocument. I am getting an exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<SomeEntity>()
.Where(s => s.JsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("Name").GetString().Contains(__name_0))' 
could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or
switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 
'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?
linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

Comment: Don't use the JsonDocument in a where or orderby. EF can't translate that into proper sql. You have to fetch all rows first and then filter.

Comment: You mean i have to do the filter client side?

Comment: Yes, unless there is an EF provider for SQL that can converrt to OPENJSON  and/or JSON_Value but I haven't seen one. Alternatively you can do a Raw Sql if you can't afford the networkload but then you have to translate your Linq clause to SQL yourself

Comment: You might be able to write custom EF functions that translate into `OPENJSON` calls, but it's going to be difficult. Raw SQL is probably a better idea.